# Search and Replace in a Trichedit

Tags: delphi

We are working with XE7. We are trying to build a search and replace feature into a `TRichEdit`.

We would like it to work just like it works in the Delphi compiler. We display our own search and replace dialog, we are not using the Delphi replace dialog.

We display the dialog, and when the user clicks the Replace button, the dialog closes, and for each instance found we want to popup a message dialog asking the user whether they want to replace that occurrence.

When we do this, the user cannot see what is selected, and if they click Yes on the message dialog, nothing is being replaced.

Our code is below:

```pascal
procedure Tviewform.select_text(fndpos:integer);
begin
   setfocus;
   asciieditor.selstart:=fndpos;
   asciieditor.sellength:=length(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata);
end;

procedure Tviewform.search_and_replace;
var position,endpos,fndans,cont:integer; foptions:tsearchtypes; msgques,stopall:word;
begin
  with asciieditor do
  begin
    endpos:=length(asciieditor.text)-vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos;
    foptions:=[];
    stopall:=0;
    cont:=0;
    if findinfo.onbut.checked then foptions:=foptions+[stMatchCase];
    lines.beginupdate;
    fndans:=findtext(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata,vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos,endpos,foptions);
    while (fndans<>-1) and (stopall=0) do
    begin
      select_text(fndans);
      msgques:=mainform.silang1.messagedlg('Replace with '+vwvars[curviewwin]^.replace+'?.',mtinformation,[mbyes,mbno,mbcancel],0);
      if msgques=mryes then
      begin
        asciieditor.clearselection;
        seltext:=vwvars[curviewwin]^.replace;
      end else
      begin
        if msgques=mrcancel then
        begin
          cont:=0;
          stopall:=1;
        end else cont:=1;
      end;
      asciieditor.Repaint;
      if cont=1 then
      begin
        inc(vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos,length(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata));
        endpos:=length(asciieditor.text)-vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos;
        fndans:=findtext(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata,vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos,endpos,foptions);
      end;
    end;
    lines.endupdate;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of issues with your code:

- You are moving input focus away from the `TRichEdit` when you call `select_text()` and `MessageDlg()`, so make sure that `TRichEdit.HideSelection` is set to `False` (it is `True` by default) in order to actually see the selection.
- You are calling `BeginUpdate()` on the `TRichEdit`, which disables screen redraws for it, including `Repaint()`.
- You don't need to call `TRichEdit.ClearSelection()` before setting the `TRichEdit.SelText`.
- When updating `vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos` after each replacement, you need to reset it to `fndAns` (the current selection's position) plus the length of `vwvars[curviewwin]^.replace` (the new text), not the length of `vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata` (the old text).  You are not moving it beyond the new text, so you are searching older text over and over.
- If the user chooses No in the `MessageDlg()`, you are not updating `vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos` to move past the text that the user didn't want to replace.
- When setting `endpos`, `length(asciieditor.text)` can be `asciieditor.gettextlen()` instead for better efficiency.  But more importantly, you should not be subtracting `vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos` from `endpos` at all.  By doing that, you are *skipping* more and more text at the end of the `TRichEdit` from the search with each replacement made.  In fact, you should be using just the `asciieditor`'s current text length as the end position of each search, so you don't actually need `endpos` at all.
- Depending on the size of your `TRichEdit` and its content, if it has scrollbars enabled, you should send the `TRichEdit` a [`EM_SCROLLCARET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-scrollcaret) message each time you find a matching text and before you prompt the user with the `MessageDlg()`, in case the matching text is off-screen.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
procedure Tviewform.search_and_replace;
var
  fndAns: Integer;
  fOptions: TSearchTypes;
  msgQues: Word;

  procedure select_text;
  begin
    {AsciiEditor.}SetFocus;
    AsciiEditor.SelStart := fndAns;
    AsciiEditor.SelLength := Length(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata);
    AsciiEditor.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
    AsciiEditor.Update;
  end;

begin
  fOptions := [];
  if FindInfo.OnBut.Checked then Include(fOptions, stMatchCase);
  repeat
    fndAns := AsciiEditor.FindText(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata, vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos, AsciiEditor.GetTextLen, fOptions);
    if fndAns = -1 then Break;
    select_text;
    msgQues := MainForm.SiLang1.MessageDlg('Replace with ' + vwvars[curviewwin]^.replace + '?', mtinformation, [mbYes,mbNo,mbCancel], 0);
    if msgQues = mrYes then
    begin
      AsciiEditor.SelText := vwvars[curviewwin]^.replace;
      AsciiEditor.Update;
      Inc(fndAns, Length(vwvars[curviewwin]^.replace));
    end
    else if msgQues = mrNo then
    begin
      Inc(fndAns, Length(vwvars[curviewwin]^.finddata));
    end else
      Break;
    vwvars[curviewwin]^.sstartpos := fndAns;
  until False;
end;
```

Comment: Hello Remy. Thank you. You are the best. Yes, you are correct that we are not advancing the search position correctly. We implemented your suggested code and it does replace the requested text correctly but the changes do not show in the Trichedit until we click cancel in the message dialog. We did change HideSelection to false in the Object Inspector but still no selected text or the replace text is shown in the trichedit until the message dialog is closed.

Comment: Hello. Anyone have any suggestions. The HideSelection inside the TRichEdit seems to be broken. Does anyone know if this is just in XE7? Thanks.

Comment: @MRoth `HideSelection` is not broken. Did you see the update I made to my answer about needing to remove `BeginUpdate()`?

Comment: Hello Remy, thanks. I didn't notice the change. It now works.